# semantic ui popup working with manual/click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I need some advice on how to get this to work.  My goal is to open a semantic popup manually after setting an angularjs scope variable.  Let's say there are 5 images, I click each one.  For every image I previously clicked, the popup doesn't open again.  And then doesn't go away.  I assume the best option for it not going away would be to have a timer/timeout to close it, but I am looking for a better option.  I also have a table that uses the click event, and when clicking from one button to another, it just closes, and has similar issues related to not opening again.

So I am looking for features similar to:

1. manual open, but closes when clicking away
2. move popup to another control immediately on click event without closing it, but still close when clicking away from those controls.

Should I attempt inline instead?  Table will have about 200 buttons, though it could have more, and this example could have even more.  They are being used more like context menu.

Horrible first attempt at js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ecjecxn/22/

```
    <div ng-repeat="page in Pages" class="item">
        <div class="ui grid">

            <a ng-if="page.Selected != null && page.Selected === true" class="twelve wide column active" ng-click="GetPageInfo(page.Id)"><span ng-repeat="n in range(page.Indention)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>{{page.Name}}</a>
            <a ng-if="page.Selected != null && page.Selected !== true" class="twelve wide column" ng-click="GetPageInfo(page.Id)"><span ng-repeat="n in range(page.Indention)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>{{page.Name}}</a>
            <div class="two wide column">
                <!-- Settings icon by Icons8 -->
                <img ng-click="SetTempPageId($event, page.Id)" class="pageCommand" src="[placeimagehere" width="20" height="20">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


          $(".pageCommand")
.popup({
    popup: $('#PagePopup'),
    on: 'manual',
    delay: {
        show: 0,
        hide: 0
    },
    lastResort: 'bottom right',
    movePopup: true,
    closable: true,
    prefer: 'opposite'
});


$scope.SetTempPageId = function ($event, id) {
    $scope.EditingPageId = id;

    $($event.target).popup('show');
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just now getting back to this, but soon after posting this answer, Instead of using semantic ui as context menu, I just used jquery contextmenu:

http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html

```
$.contextMenu({
              selector: '.command',
              callback: function (key, options) {
                  if (key == "Search") {
                      console.log("clicked search");
                      var search = $(".search").modal({ duration: 0 });
                      search.modal("show");
                  }
              },
              items: {
                  "Search": { name: "Search", icon: "search" }
              }
          });
```